# Windows GUID listings

Tags: windows, guid

I've been looking for a complete listing of important GUIDs the best I can find is http://www.myplugins.info/guids/guidlist.php although it seems like it is still missing some things like the GUID for IContextMenu. Would anyone know how to find these? Or is there a better listing of commonly used GUIDs in Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What sort of GUIDs are you looking for?  If you're looking for Windows SHELL GUIDs (like the aformentioned IContextMenu), SHLGUID.H from the Windows SDK is a good place to start...

Comment: Cool that helps. I was wondering if there was kind of some sort of compiled list of common windows guids (mostly interested in shell guids)

Thanks!